# why after creation JavaScript objects they are being removed?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to add DOM object into my html, but after adding they are being removed immediately. 
Could someone please help to debug below presented code?

```js
function addVertex () {
 var iTr = document.createElement('tr');
 var jTr = document.createElement('tr');

 iTr.id = 'block';
 iTr.className = 'block';
 jTr.className = 'block_2';
 iTr.appendChild(jTr);

 document.getElementById('vertex_table').appendChild(iTr);
}
```

```html
<form>
 <table>
  <tbody id="vertex_table">
  <tr>
   <td>Vertex start</td>
   <td>Vertex end</td>
   <td>Weight</td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
 </table>
 <input type="submit" value="Add Vertex" onclick="addVertex()"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the form is submitted when you click button with `type="submit"`. This causes page reload. I assume that in your case you don't actually need to send form. So change button type to `button` and it will work:

```
<input type="button" value="Add Vertex" onclick="addVertex()" />
```